# How to add space between bars using Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(
    pd.DataFrame({'price': prices}), 
    x="price",
    )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to separate the different bins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **'update_layout(bargap=<gap_value>'** before show it!

And for a better visualization, you can group bars by a range, like 10 to 20.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
count = np.random.randint(1, 10, 100)
price = np.random.uniform(10, 100, 100)

fig = px.histogram(x=price, y=count, nbins=20,
                   labels={'x': 'Price', 'y': 'Count'},
                   title="Histogram of Count vs Price",
                   barmode="group",
                   barnorm=None
                   )

# Insert the gap!
fig.update_layout(bargap=0.2)

fig.show()
```

My code results:

[Graph Result of Code Above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbECa.png)

You can find more information on Plotly documentation:

https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-bargap